# Nginx proxy pass not working sometimes

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx

I have a proxy server (ubuntu) that can accessible via my global IP (not have domain).

For Example 85.45.0.12:6021 and this reverse to local server. Local server (10.0.0.25) installed tomcat and running geoserver on tomcat.

I configured my proxy settings like this:

```
server {
     location /geoserver {
          proxy_pass http://10.0.0.25:8080;
          proxy_set_header Host       $proxy_host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          auth_basic "Restricted";
          auth_basic_user_file /var/work/htpasswd;
     }
}
```

When I send a request to my proxy like this **`http://85.45.0.12:6021/geoserver`** I can access to geoserver admin panel. "**Restricted**" browser login popup is appeared.

[image]

I am typing **htpasswd** username and password. And another browser login popup appearing that message "Geoserver realm".

[image]

I am typing **htpasswd** username and password but not working.

How can I solve problem? I think something is missing on proxy settings. If I do not use nginx proxy and access directly to the geoserver machine, geoserver realm popup not appear.

Comment: Is it asking for authentication when the "Restricted" message comes up?  What happens when you authenticate using the correct credentials from the htpasswd file?

Comment: Restricted message is comes up first request and I am logging in after authenticated. And I am accessing geoserver admin page. But working in admin page, some operations require Restricted. Should I set some proxy header settings?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "some operations require Restricted"?  Is it popping up another authentication dialog which says "Restricted", or is that error appearing in some other way?

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: Is the restricted message in the admin page another authentication dialog?  Where does the message appear?